# Use return in php function with if statement

Tags: php

Is there a way to use return in a function with an if statement?

I would like to see either the function was executed until the if statement or not.
This would help me to check if the sql query would be executed as well.
I know to 100% I only could check it on the sql response, but I am looking for the shortest way to figure out if the content of a function was executed or not.

Here is an example:

```
<?php 
function hi($i)
{
    return (1==$i){echo "Hello"; };
}

$i = '1';
echo hi($i);
?>
```

I try to avoid to use it like this, since I always require to add an return before the end of the if statement:

```
<?php 
function hi($i)
{
    if(1==$i){
        echo "Hello"; 
    };
    return true;
}
$i = '1';
echo hi($i); 
?>
```

Comment: Hi, not really clear what you are actually asking here. Maybe if you use a real example

Comment: can you provide more details? cant understanf what is your problem or what you cant solve

Comment: Yes, returning values within an if statement is perfectly valid. In some cases, it's preferred over echoing.

Comment: Note that you initially assign `$i = '1'` which is a character, and inside function `hi()` you are comparing it with integer type `1`. Also, you should remove `;` symbol after if curly braces `{ }`. And yes, you can definitely `return` inside `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function ifReturn($input){
    $message="";
    if ($input == 3){
        $message ="input is 3";
    
    } else {
        $message = "input is everything BUT 3";
    }
    return $message;
}


echo '<p>'.ifReturn(3).'</p>';
echo '<p>'.ifReturn(2).'</p>';
```